# HIVE Arguments in PyAthenaJDBC (AWS athena)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jdbc, hive, amazon-athena

I am using the python module called PyAthenaJDBC in order to query Athena using the provided JDBC driver.
Here is the link : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAthenaJDBC/

The connection is established successfully, the queries are working as well (Show databases, show tables,  Select ... )
However, whenever I try to define a custom table using Hive arguments such as 'ROW FORMAT SERDE..' It's not working anymore,
Here is my code :

```
class PyAthenaLoader():
    def connecti(self):
        self.conn = pyathenajdbc.connect(
                                         access_key=access_key_id,
                                         secret_key=secret_key_id,
                                         region_name = "us-west-2",
                                         s3_staging_dir="s3://aws-athena-query-results-332333536009-us-west-2")
    def create(self):
        try:
            with self.conn.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(
                              """CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sales4 (
                              Day_ID int, 
                              Product_Id string,
                              Store_Id string, 
                              Sales_Units int,
                              Sales_Cost float, 
                              Currency string
                              ) 
                              ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
                              WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
                              'serialization.format' = '|',
                              'field.delim' = '|',
                              'collection.delimm = 'undefined',
                              'mapkey.delim' = 'undefined'
                              ) LOCATION 's3://athena/';
                              """)
```

> Error : line 1:8: no viable alternative at input 'CREATE EXTERNAL'
>   (Service: AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   InvalidRequestException; Request ID:
>   0cca6f3e-fe9e-11e6-be4f-a3b28f284a77)

PS: That same query works just fine in the console management!
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is malformed.

It is due to this line:

```
'collection.delimm = 'undefined',
```

It is missing a close-quote after `delimm`.